# Magento2: How to move category description to bottom

Tags: magento2

I want move category description from top to bottom page. But above footer in full width layout (not in under products list).

From:
https://prnt.sc/tbw9yk

To:
https://prnt.sc/tbwack

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
app/design/frontend/[Company]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

**Code**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.description" destination="content.bottom" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: The element still is on the same position.

Comment: Go to Admin->System->Cache Management clear the static file cache, and are you in developer mode?